# How to open new view controller by menu button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I have a menu like

[image]

It shows only select button but I want when I select Hello 2 open Hello2 view controller.

My code :

```
enter code here

 - (IBAction)selectClicked:(id)sender {
NSArray * arr = [[NSArray alloc] init];
arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello 0", @"Hello 1", @"Hello 2", @"Hello 3", @"Hello   4", @"Hello 5", @"Hello 6", @"Hello 7", @"Hello 8", @"Hello 9",nil];
NSArray * arrImage = [[NSArray alloc] init];
arrImage = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"], [UIImage    imageNamed:@"apple2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple2.png"], nil];
if(dropDown == nil) {
    CGFloat f = 200;
    dropDown = [[NIDropDown alloc]showDropDown:sender :&f :arr :arrImage :@"down"];
    dropDown.delegate = self;
}
else {
    [dropDown hideDropDown:sender];
    [self rel];
}
 }

-(void)rel{
//    [dropDown release];
  dropDown = nil;
 }
```

Comment: set some tag to the button & as per the button selection, check which button is clicked using tag & open view controller accordingly.

Comment: What is NIDropDown class? is there a didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of table view present?

Comment: @SharanyaKM Yes there is this method in NIDropDown.m  http://pastie.org/7978703

Comment: You should mention that you using thirdparty and copy and paste from example project: https://github.com/BijeshNair/NIDropDown/blob/master/NIDropDown/NIViewController.m

Comment: Yes it is same sample.I want to edit this sample for when I select open selected view controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.. So if i'm not wrong this is the class you are using https://github.com/BijeshNair/NIDropDown/blob/master/NIDropDown.m

if you see this method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Before you do hiding of the table just pass the indexPath as a tag to the button.
btnSender.tag = indexPath.row;
[self hideDropDown:btnSender];
}
```

So when you -rel is called you can use the button tag to open a new view controller in

```
-(void)rel{
   // use button tag to open respective view controller here.
  dropDown = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The delegate method get invoked in the selection of table

```
- (void) niDropDownDelegateMethod: (NIDropDown *) sender
```

Find out which option is pressed from there and implement the push method

The problem is the code doesnt provide method for getting the value selected.You have to look into that custom class `NIDropDown` and add a value returning the selected index

Solution

.h add

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger *selectedIndex;
```

.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     self.selectedIndex=indexPath.row;//Add this line
    [self myDelegate];
}
```

and in viewcontroller

```
- (void) niDropDownDelegateMethod: (NIDropDown *) sender {
    NSLog(@"%d",sender.selectedIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By doing some modification in code you can do this

In `NIDropDown.h` add this code

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * str;
```

In `NIDropDown.m` add this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self hideDropDown:btnSender];

    UITableViewCell *c = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [btnSender setTitle:c.textLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSLog(@"%@",c.textLabel.text);

    self.str = c.textLabel.text;   //here we are setting our str variable for later use

    for (UIView *subview in btnSender.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    imgView.image = c.imageView.image;
    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:c.imageView.image];
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 25, 25);
    [btnSender addSubview:imgView];
    [self myDelegate];
}
```

In `NIViewController.m` add this code

```
- (void) niDropDownDelegateMethod: (NIDropDown *) sender {
    if ([sender.str isEqualToString:@"Hello0"]){
        //Put hello0VC transition code
        NSLog(@"dilip hello0");
    }else if ([sender.str isEqualToString:@"Hello1"]) {
        //Put hello1VC transition code
        NSLog(@"dilip hello1");
    }else if ([sender.str isEqualToString:@"Hello2"]){
        //Put hello2VC transition code
        NSLog(@"dilip hello2");
    }else if ([sender.str isEqualToString:@"Hello3"]){
        //Put hello3VC transition code
        NSLog(@"dilip hello3");
    }else if ([sender.str isEqualToString:@"Hello4"]){
        //Put hello4VC transition code
        NSLog(@"dilip hello4");
    }
    [self rel];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For that you can make custom PickerView and in that you can get this kind of view as You want.

And you have to implement pickerView's Delegate Method:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  if (row==0)
    {
        Hello1VC *VC1=[[Hello1VC alloc]initWithNibName:@"Hello1VC" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:VC1 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

likeWise you can check index and based on that you can display ViewController